# Handle all random occurring element in single element into xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm define one element in xsd file like below

```
<xs:element name="NonTeachingActivity">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="NTCode" type="String10"/>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="String100"/>
                <xs:element name="Type" type="MeetingType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="RefId" type="GUID" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

in this element sequence of element is not necessary follow order,
tag will be

> 1) NTCode,Description,Type 2) Description,NTCode,Type 3)
>   Type,NTCode,Description

so it is possible to handle all the order in given(NonTeachingActivity) single element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSD 1.0 there is two possible solutions:

1. Use `choice` inside your `sequence`:

   ```
   <xs:element name="NonTeachingActivity">
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                   <xs:element name="NTCode" type="String10"/>
                   <xs:element name="Description" type="String100"/>
                   <xs:element name="Type" type="MeetingType"/>
               </xs:choice>
           </xs:sequence>
           <xs:attribute name="RefId" type="GUID" use="required"/>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   ```

   But this will not limit amount of occurrences of each child element.
2. Another way is to use `all`:

   ```
   <xs:element name="NonTeachingActivity">
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:all>
               <xs:element name="NTCode" type="String10"/>
               <xs:element name="Description" type="String100"/>
               <xs:element name="Type" type="MeetingType"/>
           </xs:all>
           <xs:attribute name="RefId" type="GUID" use="required"/>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   ```

   But each child element can occur zero or one time.